# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on an else if line

Tags: javascript, if-statement, token

this is my pretty much my first JavaScript program.
I don't get why it won't work, I don't know how to debug properly, I used F12 on Google chrome to go in developer mode. If I load my html page, nothing happens and the consol says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else     and that the error comes from line 18.

This is my whole code, seeing as the problem might not lie on line 18 alone:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
         BMI calculator
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var leeftijd= prompt("Ben je 18 of ouder? (Ja=1)");
        if (leeftijd == 1){
                var gewicht= prompt("Geef je gewicht in in kilo's");
                var lengte= prompt("Geef je lengte in in centimeters");

                while (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0 || lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){   
                    if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
                                lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
                    else if (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0){
                                gewicht = prompt("Geef je gewicht in in kilo's");
                        }
                    }
                }
              var bmi = Math.round((gewicht / 100) / (lengte * lengte));


                if (bmi >40) { 
                        confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan extreme obesitas.");
                    else if (bmi > 30 && bmi <=40)
                        confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan obesitas.");
                    else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <=30)
                        confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan overgewicht.");
                    else if (bmi > 18 && bmi <=25)
                        confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U heeft een normale BMI.");
                    else if (bmi < 18)
                        confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan ondergewicht.");
                }
                }
        else {
        confirm("Je moet 18 of ouder zijn om je BMI te kunnen berekenen.")
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In the future, you can easily [validate your javascript online](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing `if` `else` correct

```
if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
     lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
else if (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0){
```

should be

```
if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
     lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
}  else if (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0){

^ <-- you lack closing of `if`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
            lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
```

you forgeot } after if

fixed

```
        if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
            lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
        } // <---
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not closing your if statements even your if else statement below..  must use this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
     BMI calculator
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var leeftijd= prompt("Ben je 18 of ouder? (Ja=1)");
    if (leeftijd == 1){
            var gewicht= prompt("Geef je gewicht in in kilo's");
            var lengte= prompt("Geef je lengte in in centimeters");

            while (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0 || lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){   
                if (lengte > 300 || lengte < 0.4){
                            lengte = prompt("Geef je lengte in in kilo's");
                        }
                else if (gewicht > 500 || gewicht < 0){
                            gewicht = prompt("Geef je gewicht in in kilo's");
                    }
                }
            }
          var bmi = Math.round((gewicht / 100) / (lengte * lengte));


            if (bmi >40) 
                    confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan extreme obesitas.");
                else if (bmi > 30 && bmi <=40)
                    confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan obesitas.");
                else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <=30)
                    confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan overgewicht.");
                else if (bmi > 18 && bmi <=25)
                    confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U heeft een normale BMI.");
                else if (bmi < 18)
                    confirm("Uw bmi is" + bmi + ". U lijdt aan ondergewicht.");


    else 
    confirm("Je moet 18 of ouder zijn om je BMI te kunnen berekenen.")

</script>
</body>
</html>
```